# How to refresh a list view from another activity from an DatePickerDialog in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on a project in Xamarin Android.  On my activity I have a list view of buttons :

[image]

When I click one of the buttons a DatePickerDialog comes up  :

[image]

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to refresh the activity under the DatePickerDialog after the positive button(Save Button) is clicked

Here is the code for the Save Button below on the DIALOG

```
    private async void HandlePositiveButton(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = (AlertDialog)sender;
        DateTime currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTextView.Text);
        DateTime changedDateTime = currentDate.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(Vm.CurrentTime));
        Vm.CurrentDateTime = changedDateTime;
        var success = await Vm.UpdateTimeLog();
    }
```

What I'd like to do back on the Activity for the Listview buttons I'd like to call my code for the listview adapter below :

```
        Vm.ShowCurrentUser();
        buttonCollection = await Vm.ShowButtons();
        if (buttonCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            listAdapter = new CustomButtonAdapter(this, buttonCollection);
            ButtonListview.Adapter = listAdapter;

        }
```

I've tried onPause and OnResume but those don't called after the Save Button is clicked and the dialog is dismissed.

Code for the clickevent for the button below from the baseadapter :

```
        public async void OnClick(Android.Views.View v)
        {
                Task<string> asyncClock = Vm.ClockCommand();
                string results = await asyncClock;
                var dialog = ChangeDateTimeDialogFragment.NewInstance();
                dialog.Show(this.activity.FragmentManager, "dialog");

        }
```

I've tried doing the following code in the click event for the buttons below :

```
                activity.Finish();
                activity.StartActivity(context.Intent);
```

Unfortunately this wipes out the dialog from showing up.

Comment: Does it need to happen after the dialog is dismissed? Is there any reason that the `OnClick` handler can't kick off the update? Since the date picker is a fragment, I don't think it will initiate any of the Activity's life cycle events (which you've noted trying).

Comment: There's a layer of complication the click event for the button is in a Custom Base Adapter for the list view of buttons.  So in the activity that calls the adapter I need to clear the listview and and refresh the List then reset the adapter.

Comment: By the way @DylanS  Thank you, your comment led me to the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realized that I already have the parent activity residing in the Custom Base Adapter for the parent activity that has the listview of buttons.  So in the Click Event for the Custom button for the base adapter I simply did the following and it updated the listview of buttons just fine!

```
    private class ButtonClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener
    {
        private Activity activity;
        private ObservableCollection<UserButtonLabel> buttonCollection = new ObservableCollection<UserButtonLabel>();
        private CustomButtonAdapter listAdapter;
        public ButtonClickListener(Activity activity)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public async void OnClick(Android.Views.View v)
        {
            ListView ButtonListview = activity.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ButtonListview);
            string name = (string)v.Tag;
            string text = string.Format("{0} Button Click.", name);
            Toast.MakeText(this.activity, text, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                Task<string> asyncClock = Vm.ClockCommand();
                string results = await asyncClock;
                var dialog = ChangeDateTimeDialogFragment.NewInstance();
                dialog.Show(this.activity.FragmentManager, "dialog");
                Vm.ShowCurrentUser();
                buttonCollection = await Vm.ShowButtons();
                if (buttonCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    listAdapter = new CustomButtonAdapter(activity, buttonCollection);
                    ButtonListview.Adapter = listAdapter;
                    ((BaseAdapter)this.listAdapter).NotifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }

    }

    private static UserTimeTrackingViewModel Vm
    {
        get
        {
            return App.Locator.UserTimeTracker;
        }
    }
}
```

This Button Listener is a private class that resides in the Custom BaseAdapter anyways.